# How can we specify which column should be filterable within a PXSegmentMask element

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way yo specify the columns we want to be filterable in a PXSegmentMask element.

I don't want to use the FilterByAllFields attribute because it makes the query to heavy (slow) on the database.

```
<px:PXSegmentMask CommitChanges="True" ID="edAcctCD" runat="server" DataField="AcctCD"
                              FilterByAllFields="True" AutoComplete="True">
</px:PXSegmentMask>
```

Comment: I just wonder why you set it to true?

Comment: Because if I put it to false, then filtering does not work at all.